# F is Undefined - Jquery

Tags: jquery, undefined

I have some jquery code that uses the live method of triggering events:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
  $('.cross-link').live(function() {       
    $('a[href=#2').click();
  });
});
```

Where `cross-link` elements can be generated after the DOM has loaded.

Firebug reports that `F is undefined`.  It references the last line in my jquery.js file that begins with `(function(){var Q=/((?:\((?:\([^()]+\)|[^()]+)+\)|\[(?:\[[^[\]]*\]|['"][^'"]+['"]|[^[\]'"]+)...` ect. I read that it may be the case that my Jquery library is out of date.  So I downloaded the latest version, but it produced other errors.

What should I be looking for to fix this?

Comment: Errors within libraries are generally easier to debug if you use the un-minimized code, rather than the minimized. There are some answers already posted, but as an exercise I recommend you try replacing jquery.min.js with jquery.js and see if the problem becomes any more obvious.

Comment: using jquery-1.4.3.js causes my browser(firefox, chrome, IE) to become unresponsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Live` needs even handler. Modify your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cross-link').live('click', function() {
    $('a[href=#2').click();
  });
});
```

Comment: that takes care of this problem, but now I have the "too much recursion" problem again.  I've asked this question elsewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011916/too-much-recursion-error-in-jquery/4011989#4011989

Comment: @sci: It is because of this line `$('a[href=#2').click();` You need to do it in some other way or find an alternative to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href=#2').click(); }); });
```

Can you check the above sytanx , there is some error in your code that why jquery is throwing error

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of **$('a[href=#2').click();** should be:

$('a[href="#2"]').click();